# Check Func<T> is not null without calling it

Tags: c#, function, parameters, null

Given the class:

```
public class Options<T>
{
    protected internal Func<T> GetFromDB { get; set; }
}
```

How would I check that the `GetFromDB` method itself is not null, without calling the method?  If I do:

```
if (options.GetFromDB() != null)
{
    var r = options.GetFromDB();
    ... do something
}
```

It appears to call code within the passed method twice, once for the null check and one for the actual call with return.

Comment: You could cache the results, but I don't know how you could know the return of a function without calling the function. You could also just assign the return value to a variable and check if the variable is non-null.

Comment: You should make it clear if you want to check if the *result* of the function is null or check if there has been no function provided

Comment: `options.GetFromDB() != null` is testing if the return value of executing the method is null, not the `func` itself

Comment: @MarkPeters yep you're right, have edited question

Comment: @Jonesopolis you're right, an oversight!  Thanks for spotting.

Comment: what about this ?`if ((r = options.GetFromDB()) != null)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
if (options.GetFromDB != null)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, that will execute the method.

Comment: Your example has `GetFromDB()`, not `GetFromDB`

Comment: It won't execute the method without a par of parens ()

Comment: I omitted (), so it's accessing the property rather than calling the function

Comment: Ah excellent, thank you this is a correct answer!  Also found you can solve it by having a custom getter/setter where the setter sets a bool which you can check.  This way is obviously better!